# Скрытый элемент selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Всем привет, интересует следующий вопрос. Есть окно авторизации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Окно авторизации можно просмотреть через селениум только при помощи iframe, все параметры страницы кликабельны. Использую:

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "mobile-itl-div"))).click()
```

Чтобы авторизоваться, требуется согласиться с условиями (2 чекбокс), но вот проблема, чекбокс для seleniuma полностью отсутствует, при попытке обратиться выдаёт ошибку:

```
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу найти сам элемент, через что бы не обращался.
Что я делаю не так и что можно сделать так)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте найти через xPath. Как вариант - использовать профиль пользователя, где вы уже прошли авторизацию.

Comment: Можете ли вы разместить ссылку на эту страницу?

Comment: Через xpath точно так же не отображается(

Comment: Вот ссылка: https://buff.163.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вас ввели в заблуждение - иконки "чекбоксов" не находятся на `iframe`. Это можно увидеть наведя мышку на `iframe` в инструменте разработчика, подкраситься всего лишь часть окна авторизации, а все окошко это просто `div class = "popup popup_login" ...`. Поэтому сначала ждем пока нужный "чекбокс" не станет кликабельным, кликаем на него, а затем уже переводим фокус на `iframe` и заполняем инпуты.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = r'https://buff.163.com/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

login = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
            "//a[starts-with(@onclick, 'loginModule')][contains(@onclick, 'showLogin')]")))
print(login)
login.click()

checkbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,
                    "//div[@id='agree-checkbox']/span/i")))
print(checkbox)
checkbox.click()


iframe = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@id='j_login']/iframe")
print(iframe)
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

phone = driver.find_element(By.ID, "phoneipt")
print(phone)

driver.quit()
```

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a0b5709c002ff1234bb3928f30a8ef0a", element="B56AC4079D4401125867A8F2DE62BED8_element_11")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a0b5709c002ff1234bb3928f30a8ef0a", element="B56AC4079D4401125867A8F2DE62BED8_element_17")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a0b5709c002ff1234bb3928f30a8ef0a", element="B56AC4079D4401125867A8F2DE62BED8_element_29")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="a0b5709c002ff1234bb3928f30a8ef0a", element="76D8BB17EA2F19413DB4F9C2166FD8D0_element_30")>
```